# same encryption between flutter and python [ AES ]

Tags: python, flutter, dart, encryption, aes

i want some example for encryption between python and flutter to encrypt request and response body between client and server

i found some example code for AES CRT encryption , but i cant see same result in flutter and python

can anybody help me ?

UPDATE :
Flutter crypt package not have counter parameter but python Crypto.Cipher package have counter parameter

this is sample code for python:

```py
    plaintext = '123'.encode('utf-8')
    key = '12345678911234567891123456789123'.encode("utf-8")
    iv = '12345'.encode('utf')
    iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16)
    ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int)
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
    ciphertext = aes.encrypt(plaintext)
    
    print('ctr = ' + str(ctr))
    print('iv = ' + str(base64.b64encode(iv)))
    print('iv_int = ' + str(iv_int))
    print('plaintext = ' + str(plaintext))
    print('key = ' + str(base64.b64encode(key)))
    print('ciphertext = ' + str(base64.b64encode(ciphertext)))
```

this is sample code for flutter :

```dart
  final plainText = '123';
  final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('12345678911234567891123456789123');
  final iv = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8('12345');
  final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.ctr));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  print('key = ' + key.base64);
  print('iv =' + iv.base64);
  print('encrypted = ' + encrypted.base64);
```

Comment: I have to assume you use the AES_encryption plugin from pub dev, First understand the lib code then you can adjust from there.

Comment: facing problem did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and posted a very similar question. Fortunately, I found the error by myself.

Here is the link: [Python AES CTR Mode only encrypts first two bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73566611/python-aes-ctr-mode-only-encrypts-first-two-bytes)

To summarize, the problem: Dart automatically uses the PKCS7 Padding when using AES Encryption, but Python does not anything like that.

So either you set the padding in your Dart code to null e.g.:

```
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr, padding: null)
```

or you add a PKCS7 padding to your python code with like the following:

```
# The message has to in bytes format
def pkcs7padding(message):
  pl = 16 - (len(message) % 16)
  return message + bytearray([pl for i in range(pl)])

ciphertext = aes.encrypt(pkcs7padding(plaintext))
```