# AES CTR encrypt on Flutter and failed to decrypt on python

Tags: python, flutter, encryption, aes, ctr

I have a project that needs to encrypt text on the front end using Flutter and decrypt it on Python.

After I searched, I found the way to use AES CTR in this link
[same encryption between flutter and python [ AES ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580708/same-encryption-between-flutter-and-python-aes)

After I tried that it worked on Flutter, but it didn't work on Python because I failed to `pip install pycrypto`, then I found another way in this https://cryptobook.nakov.com/symmetric-key-ciphers/aes-encrypt-decrypt-examples that i think that can work

After I tried, it failed too.

Here is my flutter code to encrypt:

```
final plainText =  "abcde";//encoded;
final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8('12345678901234567890123456789012');
final iv = enc.IV.fromUtf8('12345');
final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key, mode: enc.AESMode.ctr, padding: null));

final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);

print(encrypted.base64); => result is yJpzWuw=
```

and here is my Python code:

```
    print(text) => yJpzWuw=
    plaintext = text.encode('utf-8')
    key = '12345678901234567890123456789012'.encode("utf-8")
    iv = '12345'.encode('utf-8')

    iv_int = int.from_bytes(iv)
    aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(key, pyaes.Counter(iv_int))
    decrypted = aes.decrypt(plaintext)
    print('Decrypted:', decrypted)
```

This is the result when I print the decrypted

```
Decrypted: b'\xe7:\xcb\x94\xbe\xbb\xf8\x1c'
```

Am I missing something? Or is there another way to encrypt in Flutter than decrypt in Python? I would be glad for any help.

**==Solution from comment ==
Change the code in python with below code**

```
ciphertext = base64.b64decode('yJpzWuw=')                       # Base64 decode the Base64 encoded ciphertext
key = '12345678901234567890123456789012'.encode("utf-8")
iv = '12345\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'.encode('utf-8')              # Pad the IV to 16 bytes with 0x00 values
iv_int = int.from_bytes(iv, 'big')                              # Convert the binary data into an int (big endian order)                           
aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(key, pyaes.Counter(iv_int))
decrypted = aes.decrypt(ciphertext)
print('Decrypted:', decrypted)
```

Comment: The post is missing links to or names of the used libraries, so that this must be determined tediously from the links or guessed. In addition the codes are not executable (not defined variables etc.). Likewise complete test data are missing (apart from key and IV plaintext and ciphertexts for both codes are needed).

Comment: Regarding the bugs: In the Dart code, an invalid IV is used (the length of the IV must match the block length of the algorithm used, otherwise the Dart library silently pads with 0x00 values). The Python code is missing the Base64 decoding of the ciphertext. Also, the IV is incorrectly converted to an integer (easiest with `int.from_bytes()`). If this is fixed, decryption works.

Comment: @Topaco : i have edit my question, after i try int.from_bytes(), but i still failed to decrypt, i don't understand about your comment that said  The Python code is missing the Base64 decoding of the ciphertext, can you give a example?

Comment: `text` is the Base64 encoded ciphertext which must not be UTF-8 encoded but Base64 decoded (`ciphertext = base64.b64decode('yJpzWuw=')`). BTW the term *plaintext* is misleading, this is the ciphertext. The IV in the Dart code is still invalid (for AES the IV must be 16 bytes long) or is not corrected in the Python code according to the Dart logic (padded with 0x00 values to 16 bytes).

Comment: @Topaco : i think python code is incorrect in iv counter.. but i dont know how to fix it...
in first link that i attach is use :
iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16);
 ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int);
 aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr);

Aes is PyCrypto that i failed to pip install, so i try other way from second link which is is use pyeas that i think will work because both is AES

Comment: I have already told you the reason repeatedly. The IV is invalid. For AES the IV must be 16 bytes large. If you still use an invalid IV in the Dart code, you must explicitly make the corrections in the Python code that the Dart code implicitly makes, namely padding the IV with 0x00 values to 16 bytes. This fixed IV is then to be converted to an int.

Comment: Run the fixed Python code online: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/HauntingPeriodicTrialsoftware#main.py

Comment: @Topaco : woww.. that's work... how i vote your answer.. .. Any way... thank you so much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was not a specific question, and it was answered in the comments.